# Standardization of software

Tags: programming, c++

I am a CSE undergrad 1st yr student. I would like to know how software that companies use change from time to time. Can't they have a single standard software?

For example: in my school they suggested me to use Borland C++ but I also had Turbo C++ in my PC so I realized that it was some except some variations were there.

If so suggest me a site where you can come across standard software for different languages.

Comment: I think this is off topic here and have voted to close, so won't give a full answer. Companies, however, change what they use to develop software because the need change constantly and the quality of tools change as well. New opportunities open and companies look to take advantage of them. The same is true for educators, in fact. The C++ standard today is so different from the original that it is barely recognizable as the same.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry to say that this is off-topic here.  This site is about how to *teach* CS.  I'm not sure which network this would be topical.  However, you are still welcome to take a look around, and ask and answer questions about teaching CS.  We welcome student perspectives here :)

Comment: There are standards for C++. Good compilers will comply to these standards, is that if you write a program in one, it will compile in the others. However on the subject of choice of language, for a beginner. Do not ask what will I be using in industry, ask what is the best language to help me learn. When we teach our kids to read, do we ask what will they need to read at work, let us start there.

Answer (score 2):

Programming languages are like tools. Different tools are better for different tasks. Hammers are useful for certain tasks, and saws are useful for other tasks. The same is true of programming languages and other programming tools.

For example, one construction company might get their [wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumber) from a place that only sells full-sized logs, which they then have to saw into individual lumber pieces. Another company might get their wood from a place that sells individual lumber pieces, so they don't have to saw it themselves. That first company would require more saws than the second company.

Back to programming: maybe one company designs software for embedded systems. They'd probably use more C, or maybe even machine language. Another company might design web applications. They would be more likely to use JavaScript or other web technologies.

Even with C++, there can be differences. Maybe one company is working with a legacy system that requires them to use a particular version of C++, but another company is only working with a single system so they can use the latest and greatest version.

Each company is working towards a slightly different set of goals, so their technology (the set of tools they use) is going to be slightly different. You aren't going to find a single source of "standard software" because there's no such thing.

Comment: Well said! I think this every time I see people arguing over why their tool/language is the best and why everyone everywhere should just use what they are using. Every tool has a time and a place.